# Create an array of object properties for each item that has the same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm merging two objects together to create a filter object. However I want to group the merged objects property values where the keys are the same.

So...

```
[{category: 'furniture'}, {category: 'mirrors'}, {availability: 'in_stock'}]
```

becomes

```
[{category: ['furniture', 'mirrors']}, {availability: 'in_stock'}]
```

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 3):

With lodash you merge the entire array to a new object by spreading into `_.mergeWith()`. The customizer should use empty arrays as default values for the current values, and concat the values. Use `_.map()` to convert back to an array.

```js
const data = [{category: 'furniture'}, {category: 'mirrors'}, {availability: 'in_stock'}];

const result = _.map(
  _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (a = [], b = [], key) => a.concat(b)),
  (val, key) => ({ [key]: val })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Using vanilla JS, reduce the array to a Map using the objects' keys as the keys of the Map, with an empty array as the value, and push the objects' values into the arrays. Use `Array.from()` to convert the Map to an array.

```js
const data = [{category: 'furniture'}, {category: 'mirrors'}, {availability: 'in_stock'}];

const result = Array.from(
  data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj)
      .forEach(([key, val]) => {
        if(!acc.has(key)) acc.set(key, [])

        acc.get(key).push(val)
      })

    return acc
  }, new Map()),
  ([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val })
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried lodash but couldnt find a specific way to achieve the desired output. As I already have lodash in the project I'm gonna give this one a go.

Comment: Lodash solution working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```js
const data = [
  { category: 'furniture' }, 
  { category: 'mirrors' }, 
  { availability: 'in_stock' }
];

const result = data.reduce(
  (a, x) => {
    const key = Object.keys(x)[0]; // find the key of the current object
    if (!a.tmp[key]) { // if the current key doesn't exist in the lookup object (tmp) yet ...
      a.tmp[key] = []; // create an empty array in the lookup object for the current key
      a.result.push({ [key]: a.tmp[key] }); // push the current object to the result
    }
    a.tmp[key].push(x[key]); // push the current value to the array
    return a;
  }, 
  { result: [], tmp: {} },
).result;

console.log(result);
```

I'm sure there are easier ways to achieve this, but that's the best I can come up with right now.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Comment: @DanEmery ... the above solution is neither *amazing* nor clever in any way. It is error prone at least twice for firstly `reduce` does not allow/implement/recognize a `thisArg` parameter, and secondly, even if `thisArg` was supported, an arrow function could not access the correct `this` since arrow functions do not have an own binding to `this`. Thus *Đinh Carabus'* solution directly writes to and reads from the global object (`window` for browsers) for the lookup task.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, You're right, I somehow got that mixed up with `Array.prototype.forEach`. I'll fix that, thanks!

Comment: @PeterSeliger, what would be your suggestion for a better solution? I'd be very interested in learning from you.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus ... I would implement the reducer function even more generic, though the OP and the example data do not ask for it. Right now the solution works property name agnostic, but assuming objects with a single key only. One could come up with an approach that supports multi-key objects. Also, it seems like the OP wants to keep the original structure for objects which have a sole unique property name, whereas the above current solution merges and collects `{ availability: ['in_stock'] }` instead of leaving it untouched as with the OP's requirements ... `{ availability: 'in_stock' }`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, yeah I noticed the problem with unique elements as well. Thank you for the hints!

Comment: @DanEmery ... The target data structure can not be left that ambiguous. One has to consequently push every same key value into an array, even though such a key (property name) was unique throughout all the other data. Keeping it ambiguous the problems occur as soon as a value is an array itself. A process has no chance (of cause with a lot of additional code it would work) figuring out if it was an initial value or the array the current item needs to be pushed to.

Answer (score 1):

we can also achieve this by using `forEach` loop **:**

```js
const input = [{category: 'furniture'}, {category: 'mirrors'}, {availability: 'in_stock'}];

const resultObj = {};
const resultArr = [];

input.forEach((obj) => {
  resultObj[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = [];
})

input.forEach((obj) => {
  resultObj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].push(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
  resultArr.push(resultObj);
})

console.log([...new Set(resultArr)]);
```

Comment: Nice solution, will give it a go!

Comment: @DanEmery Thanks. Kindly do accept and upvote if it helps you.

Comment: @CreativeLearner this doesn't quite match the desired output format. You have merged the properties into one object instead of keeping them in seperate objects as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Another one reduce solution

```js
const arr = [{category: 'furniture', category2: 'furniture2'}, {category: 'mirrors'}, {availability: 'in_stock'}]


const result = Object.values(arr
  .flatMap((obj) => Object.entries(obj))
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = acc[key] 
      ? {[key]: [...acc[key][key], value] } 
      : {[key]: [value] }
  
  return acc;
  }, {}));
  
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic implementation could achieve a merger of any kind of objects regardless of amount and kind of an(y) object's property names.

Since the result of such an implementation is an object, one needs additional treatment in order to cover the OP's requirement(s).

```js
function mergeAndCollectItemEntries(result, item) {
  // return the programmatically aggregated merger/result.
  return Object
    // get an item's entry array.
    .entries(item)
    // for each key-value pair ...
    .reduce((merger, [key, value]) => {

      // ... access and/or create a `key` specific array ...
      // ... and push `value` into this array.
      (merger[key] ??= []).push(value);

      // return the programmatically aggregated merger/result.
      return merger;

    }, result);
}

const sampleData = [
  { category: 'furniture' },
  { category: 'mirrors' },
  { availability: 'in_stock' },
];
const mergedData = sampleData
  .reduce(mergeAndCollectItemEntries, {});

const mergedDataList = Object
  .entries(
    sampleData
      .reduce(mergeAndCollectItemEntries, {})
  ) 
  .map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]));
//.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log({
  sampleData,
  mergedData,
  mergedDataList,
});
console.log(
  Object
    .entries([
        { category: 'furniture', foo: 'baz' },
        { category: 'mirrors', bar: 'bizz' },
        { availability: 'in_stock', bar: 'buzz' },
      ].reduce(
        mergeAndCollectItemEntries, {}
      )
    ).map(
      ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value })
    //entry => Object.fromEntries([entry])
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach here with building an tracking object to merge the values.

Handle the cases of single value keep as string and multiple values as array per the expected output.

```js
const merge = (arr, output = {}) => {
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const [[key, val]] = Object.entries(item);
    if (key in output) {
      output[key] = Array.isArray(output[key])
        ? output[key].concat(val)
        : [output[key]].concat(val);
    } else {
      output[key] = val;
    }
  });
  return Object.entries(output).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }));
};

const data = [
  { category: "furniture" },
  { category: "mirrors" },
  { availability: "in_stock" },
];

console.log(merge(data));
```